# Zend_Acl, How to check a user with multiple roles for resource access

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl

i am implementing RBAC for my app, and everything is managed from database.

for example i am storing all resources/permissions in a table called `permission` , all roles in `role` table, and another table called `role_permission` to define which role have access to which resources/permissions.

the purpose for going with this approach is because i want the administrator of the app to create the `role` and assign the permission to role by himself.

User of the app can have multiple roles for example `administrator`, `supervisor`, `player`, `referee` etc.

I created a model class for `Zend_Acl` to add roles and resources and assign permission to it.

Below is what i did.

```
foreach($this->_roles as $role) {
    $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role($role['id']));
}
foreach($this->_permissions as $permmission) {
    $this->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource($permmission['id']));
}
foreach($this->_rolePermissions as $value) {
    $this->allow($value['role_id'], $value['permmission_id']);
}
$this->allow($this->_roleAdmin);
```

it works fine if i want to check wether a permission exist for a particular role for example by using this code.

```
echo $acl->isAllowed($role, $permission) ? 'allowed' : 'denied';
```

however i want to check with multiple roles wether the current permission exist for a user with multiple roles.

how am i supposed to check wether the user with multiple roles such as `referee`, `supervisor`  has the access to resource `create report`. with isAllowed() you can only check for permission for only 1 role.

Comment: Its been awhile, but IIRC the Zend_ACL was hierarchical so you would take role at a certain point and it would resolve the permissions baesd on the the tree... ofcours if your roles are different trees then that doesnt help...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The approach I usually take is to create a class that extends `Zend_Acl`, and extend the `isAllowed()` function so it can take my user object as a parameter instead. It then loops through that user's roles performing the check for each one. E.g.:

```
public function isAllowed($roleOrUser = null, $resource = null, $privilege = null)
{
    if ($roleOrUser instanceof Users_Model_User) {
        // check each of that user's roles
        foreach ($roleOrUser->roles as $role) {
            if (parent::isAllowed($role, $resource, $privilege)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    } else {
        return parent::isAllowed($roleOrUser, $resource, $privilege);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a way that scales so I'm attempting to drop loops if possible. Is there a way to access all the roles that are allowed for a given resource from the acl object? That way I can check my array of roles and see if it is one of the ones allowed to access the resource.

Comment: Such a method would still need to loop through the roles and check them in succession. Presumably users don't have that many roles so I doubt this would be any sort of performance problem.

Comment: If anyone have trouble extending; this page helped me http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/extending

Comment: Clever solution, might be cleaner to split into a separate method like `isUserAllowed($user, $resource = null, $privilege = null)` or alike, but it works.